# Ошибка при обновлении данных в MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Есть таблица в базе данных

```
    create table pre_Accounts
(
    pre_account_id int auto_increment primary key,
    mail varchar(64) not null,
    password varchar(128) not null,
    solt varchar(128) not null,
    confirm_token varchar(128) not null,
    confirm bool default false
);
```

Хочу обновить данные в ней, а конкретно в столбце confirm - сменить с false на true. Задаю такую команду:

```
update pre_Accounts set confirm = true where pre_account_id = 1;
```

Однако СУБД мне выдает ошибку:

```
Error Code: 1436. Thread stack overrun:  8196 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

Помогите разобраться кто знает..

Comment: У вас в вопросе есть ответ: Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack. Либо в конфигурационном файле добавьте
thread_stack = 512K. Перезапустите mysql

Comment: Спасибо все исправил - заработало, однако появилась новая проблема http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619287/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-mysql