# Ошибки в работе триггера MySQL

Tags: mysql, триггер

Есть триггер :

```
    DELIMITER //
create trigger betdesk_db.after_update_confirm
after update on pre_Accounts for each row
begin
insert into Accounts(mail, `password`, solt, role_id) values (NEW.mail, NEW.password, NEW.solt, 2);
delete from pre_Accounts where NEW.pre_account_id = pre_account_id;
end; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Смысл таков, что при обновлении данных  в таблице `pre_Accounts`, они переносятся в таблицу `Accounts` и удаляются.
Однако ошибка возникает при обновлении данных:

```
update pre_Accounts set confirm = true where pre_account_id = 1;
```

Данные не обновляются из-за следующей ошибки:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'pre_accounts' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Где я ошибся, подскажите..

Comment: Почему нельзя сразу работать с нужной таблицей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас причина указана в вопросе "because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." Другими словами вы не можете в триггере after update для таблицы удалять из этой же таблицы. Как вариант можно попробовать удалить запись в триггере для таблицы Acсounts

Comment: Не взлетит. Если срабатывает каскад триггеров, то нельзя модифицировать ни одну таблицу, которая породила хотя бы один триггер